# Turbo_stream format not being sent anymore

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hotwire-rails, turbo-rails

we are currently working on changing our web app search engine from Stimulus to Turbo.

However, we keep getting an HTML request instead of a Turbo one from our script with the error : “

```
ActionController::UnknownFormat “.
Trying to force the request into the Turbo format give the following error :
“ ActionController::UnknownFormat - SearchController#search is missing a template for this request format and variant.
request.formats: ["text/html"]
request.variant: []: “
```

We are on the 7.0.0-beta.5 Turbo version.

View

```
<h1>All Apps</h1>
<%= turbo_frame_tag "record" do %>
  <%= form_with url: "/search", method: :get , data: { controller: "search" }  do |form| %>
    <%= form.text_field :search , data: { action: "input->search#findResults" } %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
<%= turbo_frame_tag "apps" do %>
  <ul>
    <% @apps.each do |app| %>
      <%= content_tag :li, app.name %>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
<% end %>

<turbo-stream action="update" target="apps">
  <template>
    <ul>
      <% @apps.each do |app| %>
        <%= content_tag :li, app.name %>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  </template>
</turbo-stream>

class SearchController < ApplicationController
  def search
    @apps = ItunesConnect::App.where("name like ?", "#{params[:search]}%")
    respond_to do |format|
       format.turbo_stream
       #format.html  { redirect_to root_url(search: params[:search]) } #for testing
    end
  end
end
```

Any advises ?

Answer (score 7):

Just encounter the very same problem: form with `method: :get` does not send a request with `TURBO_STREAM` format (it is `HTML`).

Aidan's answer is almost correct - `format: :turbo_stream` should be specified explicitly. It should not be an argument's hash element but a URL's parameter, like this:

```rb
<%= form_with URL: search_path(format: :turbo_stream), method: :get , data: { controller: "search" } do |form| %>
```

Comment: When I do this the browser downloads the response as a file. Any idea why?

Answer (score 2):

When defining a route manually with `get`, for example, you should specify the default format like this:

```
get :search, to: 'search#index', defaults: { format: :turbo_stream }
```

Comment: THIS is what finally got my requests to be processed as TURBO_STREAM instead of HTML. Nothing else worked.

Comment: Does `Turbo.setFormMode('optin')` override this? I've tried everything in this thread and none of it is working, including this change to routes. (I'm trying to get a `link_to(data: { turbo: true })` to send a turbo request, not a form.)

Answer (score 0):

I may have just had a similar problem. I think you need to specify `format: :turbo_stream` as one of your options to `form_with`. In my case, I wanted to hit the HTML block but the form kept hitting turbo_stream instead.

To be extra clear, this

```
<%= form_with url: "/search", method: :get , data: { controller: "search" }  do |form| %>
```

becomes this

```
<%= form_with url: "/search", method: :get , data: { controller: "search" }, format: :turbo_stream  do |form| %>
```