# Rails `link_to` with data-turbo doesnt get TURBO_STREAM request format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, turbo, turbo-rails

(Original question: Does `Turbo.setFormMode("optin")` disable turbo requests in links? No, the link doesn't work even with `Turbo.setFormMode("on")`)

Mature app using Rails 6.1, recently added gem `turbo-rails` 1.5.0, gem `importmap-rails` 1.2.3 to start converting forms to Hotwire.

```rb
# app/javascript/application.js
import "@hotwired/turbo-rails"
Turbo.setFormMode("optin")
```

In a translation page `erb` template, I have links like this that should GET a turbo-stream request for a tiny edit form. The response should update a separate turbo-frame (or a div, have tried both), elsewhere on the page, replacing it with the edit form.

The issue is that these links are not sending `request.format turbo-stream`, they're sending `request.format text/html`. The links are built with a helper like this:

```rb
link_to(label, edit_translation_path(id: t_tag, locale: @lang.locale),
        data: { turbo: true, turbo_frame: "translation_ui",
                tag: t_tag, role: "show_tag" })
```

Controller action, nothing crazy, has worked for years with UJS:

```rb
  def edit
    @lang = set_language_and_authorize_user
    @tag = params[:id]
  rescue StandardError => e
    @msg = error_message(e).join("\n")
  end
```

The response template:

```rb
# app/views/translations/edit.erb

<%= turbo_stream.replace("translation_ui") do
  render(partial: "translations/form", layout: false)
  render(partial: "translations/versions", layout: false)
end %>
```

If I test the page in the browser, turbojs is being loaded, there are no js errors, the HTML is correctly built. Note that the "index" contains links to update a separate turbo-frame on the right, where the edit form should load. It doesn't need to be a turbo-frame — I've tried this as a div with an id.

```
<!-- app/views/translations/index.erb produces this html -->

<div id="translation_index">
  <a data-turbo="true" data-turbo-frame="translation_ui" 
     data-tag="hello" data-role="show_tag" 
     href="/translations/hello/edit?locale=en"><span class="tag">hello</span></a>
  <a data-turbo="true" data-turbo-frame="translation_ui" 
     data-tag="hello" data-role="show_tag" 
     href="/translations/hello/edit?locale=en"><span class="tag"> goodbye</span></a>
</div>
<turbo-frame id="translation_ui"></turbo-frame>
```

But clicking the link does not send a GET `request.format == turbo_stream` to the controller, the request.format is `text/html` or `*/*`. This is what I get in the console:

```
Started GET "/translations/one/edit?locale=en" for ::1 at 2023-11-06 00:31:30 -0800
Processing by TranslationsController#edit as HTML
  Parameters: {"locale"=>"en", "id"=>"one"}
```

Turbo links work elsewhere in the app. Why is this happening?

Note there is `Turbo.setFormMode = optin` and I'm aware that setting `data-turbo=false` on any ancestors of the element would disable Turbo for all children, but that is not the case here.

Things I have tried:

- modifying the link path `edit_translation_path(format: "turbo-stream")` per [this SO Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67309874/turbo-stream-format-not-being-sent-anymore)
- modifying the route `get(:edit, to: "translations#edit", as: "edit_translation", defaults: { format: :turbo_stream })` per [this SO Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67309874/turbo-stream-format-not-being-sent-anymore)
- adding `Turbo.session.drive = true` to `app/javascript/application.js`, per [this issue](https://github.com/hotwired/turbo/pull/500)
- `link_to(data: { turbo_method: :get }` per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75657122/3357635)
- `Turbo.setFormMode("on")` in `app/javascript/application.js`

WTF! None of this has any effect on the request.format sent from the links.

Comment: Perhaps you can eleborate on what you are expecting.  At least for me it's not that clear. From what I can see you have to decide, if the change is initiated from the server (that's why you are using turbo_stream) or from the client (as you are opting into turbo). I guess that you want to respond to a click - here you do not need a turbo-stream. Wrap your form or parts of it into a turbo-frame AND BE SURE to include the turbo-frame-definition in your response - see here: https://turbo.hotwired.dev/handbook/frames

Comment: And perhaps you could share your partials

Comment: Thanks @zaphodbln_. I've updated to show more of the "index" template, and the `edit` response partial is there in the answer - the frame or div to be updated is separate from the originating link. The deeper issue is that the click is not sending as a turbo request — I'm sure of this because when I break during the Rails controller's `edit` action in the Ruby console, and check `request.format`, it's "text/html". In other words the issue seem not that the controller can't figure out the right turbo response, it's that the request is wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `data-turbo-stream` specifies that a link or form can accept a Turbo Streams response. Turbo automatically requests stream responses for form submissions with non-`GET` methods;
> `data-turbo-stream` allows Turbo Streams to be used with `GET` requests as well.

*https://turbo.hotwired.dev/reference/attributes*

*GET* links and *GET* forms need to have `data-turbo-stream` attribute to send a *TURBO_STREAM* request:

```rb
<%= link_to "GET link", "/", data: {turbo_stream: true} %>

<%= form_with url: "/", method: :get, data: {turbo_stream: true} do |f| %>
  <%= f.submit "GET form" %>
<% end %>
```

With `Turbo.setFormMode("optin")` you also have to specify `data-turbo="true"` for the form:

```rb
<%= form_with url: "/", method: :get,
  data: {
    turbo: true,
    turbo_stream: true
  } do |f| %>

  <%= f.submit "GET form" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks @Alex - holy cr*p that's it! Is it certain that `data-turbo-frame` won't set the request format on a GET link? Or maybe, not if the link is not originating from within the turbo-frame itself? 

Also want to note for others that I had to remove the path helper param `format: :turbo_stream`, and everything else i'd thrown at this to make it work. Jeebus that stumped me for hours.

Comment: specifying `data-turbo-frame` doesn't change the format it stays as *HTML*, the only thing it does is set a `Turbo-Frame` header with the name of the frame (by default it's only used to skip rendering a layout for turbo frame requests). however, you could technically render a turbo_stream as a response to a turbo frame requests.

Comment: Thanks. I notice that if i set both `data: { turbo_stream: true, turbo_frame: "translation_ui" })` on the link, changing both the page element and my response template to a `turbo_frame_tag`, that doesn't update. So I'm keeping it simple with divs and `turbo_stream:update`. That works!